# Java Array Slice error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to put the lowest five numbers from one array (they are array objects) into an array by themselves. Here's my code, this is after pulling the array objects into their own array and sorting that array in ascending order. From there I'm trying to keep the lowest 5 items in the array. If there's 5 or more scores I figured slicing the array to keep the first 5 would be the easiest method, if there's less than 5, just copy from one array to the other.

```
  if(scoreID > 5){
     int lowestScores = scoreArray.slice(0,6);
  } 
  else { 
     for(int i=0;i<scoreID;i++) {
        int[] lowestScores = new int[scoreID];
        lowestScores[i] = scoreArray[i];}
  }
```

scoreID is just a place holder for the number of scores that the primary array is stored.

The error I'm getting is...

```
Golfer.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
    int lowestScores = scoreArray.slice(0,6);
                                  ^
symbol:   method slice(int,int)
location: variable scoreArray of type int[]
1 error
```

Comment: Change it to `int[] lowestScores = scoreArray.slice(0,6);`

Comment: You are trying to assign an `int[]` to an `int` variable.

Comment: And there is no `slice()` method in Java unless you implemented it yourself.

Comment: @pp_ even if he implemented `slice()` I don't think he can use a `.` after his *scoreArray* to use the method. Maybe could be something like `slice(scoreArray, 0, 6)`

Comment: @Shadowfax You're right, to be able to do `scoreArray.slice()` he would have to actually modify the `Arrays` class in the `java.util` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Arrays.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int))

In you code

```
int[] lowestScores  = Arrays.copyOf(scoreArray, 5);
```

As per the javadocs

> a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with zeros to obtain
>   the specified length

By the way `slice` is a javaScript method.

Comment: Thank you, will mark answer. Didn't realize slice was JS not java.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int [] b = new int [] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};


int [] copiedto = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 0, 4);
```

Give it a try hope this may help rather than slice method.